# Can NSManagedObject attribute contain a reference to another NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, core-data

Please forgive me if I do this wrong, it's my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. And... it looks like I don't have enough reputation to include a screenshot, so here is a link instead. Sorry.
[>> Image of my xcdatamodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnueK.png)

So anyway, I've got an **NSManagedObject** subclass called **Category**, which has a relationship of one-to-many to a subclass called **Exercise**.

I'd like to have an attribute in my **Category** class that could contain a reference to a particular "active" **Exercise**. So my question is: *is that possible? And if so, what attribute type would I use?*

So far I've been using a simple Int16, and tracking an index attribute on my Exercise objects, but it becomes troublesome when the user starts rearranging cells in a TableView, deleting, etc. The calculations to track the correct object seem really error prone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add a to-one relationship to the active exercise ...

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something easy I was missing. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize @Martin-R's answer, you would add a to-one relationship on your `Category` entity to your `Exercise` entity.

[image]

Indicated here with the relationship 'activeExercise <- -> inverseActiveExercise'.